# Given two continuous random variables, why is it that this conditional property is true?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, integral

I have to prove the following property given that $X$ and $Y$ are both random variables and $B$ is any set within the range of $Y$:

$$P(Y\in B|X=x)=\int_Bf_{Y|x}(y)dy$$

My attempt (starting from the right side since I am not sure not to begin from the left side):

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_Bf_{Y|x}(y)dy
&=\int_B\frac{f_{XY}(x, y)}{f_X(x)}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{f_X(x)}\int_Bf_{XY}(x, y)dy\\
&=\frac{1}{f_X(x)}P(X=x, Y\in B)
\end{align*}
$$

and I am not sure how to go from there.

Comment: Using the relationship $P(X=x, Y \in B) = P(Y \in B|X = x)P(X = x)$ gets you most of the rest of the way there.

Comment: @jbowman Still not sure how to get rid of the $\frac{1}{f_X(x)}$ and $P(X=x)$ after the substituion.

Comment: Wait nvm, I realized that $P(X = x) = f_X(x)$ and so the $f_X(x)$ at the bottom would cancel out. Thanks!